# I wonder what is impact of xml and csv on google bot?

Tags: xml, csv, compare

I'm using csv to submit product data via google merchant. It takes time for Google bot to crawl, about 24 hours. I would like to know if I use xml file instead, will google's data crawl rate improve? Thank you for your help